Flutter Integration Test Cannot Access Environment Variable
I'm working on a Flutter project and set an environment variable for testing. However, during integration tests, the variable is not accessible. Here’s what I did:
Set an environment variable:
export my_key='your_api_key_here'

Verified the environment variable:
echo $my_key

Tried accessing it in the Flutter test with and both of them are not working
const key = String.fromEnvironment("my_key")
final key1 = Platform.environment['my_key']

Checked all environment variables and saw that my_key is not there. The environment is different.
Ran the tests with:
flutter test integration_test/test_feature.dart -d emulator-5554

The environment variable my_key is not accessible during the test. It seems the test environment is isolated and does not inherit my terminal's environment variables.
How can I ensure my Flutter integration tests access the environment variables I set? Any recommendations to pass environment variables to the Flutter test environment?

The emulator is a separate, virtual machine.  It has its own operating system and environment separate from your development machine.

You can simply use --dart-define to pass into your flutter test command:
Ex:
flutter test integration_test/test_feature.dart -d emulator-5554 --dart-define=my_key=your_api_key_here.

And it can be easily accessed in the code as you mentioned:
const key = String.fromEnvironment("my_key")

